# Parse Cloud Code request.user returns null on class beforeSave()

Tags: java, parsing, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to limit the access for each created new item in the class `Lista`, but `request.user` is always set to `null`.

How can I get the request originator through Cloud Code?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Lista", function (request, response) {
    var requestUser = request.user; 
    var newACL = new Parse.ACL(requestUser);

    newACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
    request.object.setACL(newACL);
    response.success();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what sdk are you using? i switched to 1.9.0 and this bug disappeared...

https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse/1.9.0

Comment: Sorry for the long time... I was actually sing the Parse Cloud Code, that is, the solution on the cloud to avoid local processing in the client.